# How to find passwords with regex

Tags: java, regex

A password consists of digits and Latin letters in any case;
a password always follow by the "password" word (in any case), but they can be separated by any number of spaces and the colon : characters.

I try this regular expression

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("password\\s\\w*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

If text is

```
    String text = "My email javacoder@gmail.com with password    SECRET115. Here is my old PASSWORD: PASS111.\n";//scanner.nextLine();
```

We need to find SECRET115 and PASS111.
Now program fails and cannot find pattern.

Comment: Can you please try if this helps: (?<=password | password:)[a-z 0-9]* , Although this also matches the spaces which can be trimmed later

Comment: There is a space between pawsword and password:)[a-z 0-9]*

Comment: (?<=password|password:)[^:][a-z 0-9]* this should help then

Answer (score 0):

You may add an optional `:` after `password`, and match 0 or more whitespaces with `\s*`:

```
password:?\s*(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/17m2vT/1/).

**Details**

- `password` - a fixed string
- `:?` - 1 or 0 colons
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/0suFSM):

```
String s = "My email javacoder@gmail.com with password    SECRET115. Here is my old PASSWORD: PASS111.\n";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("password:?\\s*(\\w+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Output:

```
SECRET115
PASS111
```